# MKAnnotationView viewForAnnotation never called

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, delegates, mkmapview

after i spend 2 days of searching the bug i have to ask for help here. i do have MapViewController and place some pins on the map. i´ve copied most of the code from MapCallouts and WeatherMap of the apple code samples.

anyhow it seems that i´ve deleted or missed essential parts. it seems there is no connection between the MapViewController and the following code

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"MKAnnotationView");
    return nil;
}
```

setting an annotation looks like this and it works well:

```
- (void)createPoi:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)theCoordinate
{
    NSLog(@"createPoi");

    RandomAnnotation *randomAnnotation = [[RandomAnnotation alloc] init];
    [randomAnnotation setTheCoordinate:theCoordinate];
    [randomAnnotation setTheTitle:@"bla"];
    [randomAnnotation setTheSubTitle:@"bla"];
    [self.mapAnnotations insertObject:randomAnnotation atIndex:kRandomAnnotationIndex];
    [randomAnnotation release];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:[self.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:kRandomAnnotationIndex]];
}
```

i can´t figure out what's wrong. could anybody give me a hint what´s missing? i have to admit that i don´t have any experience with the delegate pattern.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure the map view's `delegate` property is set.

If the map is created in IB, right-click on it and hook up its delegate outlet to File's Owner.

If the map is created in code, set the delegate after creating the map view:

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: aah. yes! i forgot to hook the map in IB to the file´s owner delegate. shame on me :-/

problem solved!

thank you very much for your fast help!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the .h where your MKMapView is declared and where your declare viewForAnnotation method, be sure to add MKMapViewDelegate in the list of protocols your class should include :

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    MKMapView *_mapView;
}
```

Then in the viewDidLoad method, be sure to to add

```
_mapView.delegate = self;
```

You can also assign the delegate of the mapView in interface builder if you've done things using it !